# How to properly share a folder between few docker containers in read mode?

Tags: docker

I have Docker installed in top of a CentOS system.

I tried to use **volume** but each new container is deleting (or hidding) the content of the folder to share.

My volume is always empty after a Docker run.

In order to create my containers, I use

```
docker run -dit --name $CONTAINER_NAME  -p $PORT:8080 \
-v $VOLUME_PATH:/opt/conf/ \
$IMAGE_NAME
```

I aim at sharing a folder from the host between few Docker containers (to READ) AND I want also to write into this folder from the host.

What is an elegant way to do that ?

Comment: Did you try the obvious way (mount the host folder into several containers)? Did it work or which difficulties did you face?

Comment: The problem is when I create a container (docker run -v ....), It is deleting all file. The volume is always empty after a docker run.

Comment: Then **that** should be your question!  With the exact command-line you're using.

Comment: docker run -dit --name $CONTAINER_NAME  -p $PORT:8080 \
-v $VOLUME_PATH:/opt/conf/ \
$IMAGE_NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use volume field.

## Create a volume

```
docker volume create  --name <volume-name>
```

## Create containers foo and bar that witl be mapped to the volume

```
docker run -dit --name foo -v test-volume:/path/in/container/ <image-name>
docker run -dit --name bar -v test-volume:/path/in/container/ <image-name>
```

Each container that will write in the volume will be visible by other.

Comment: Btw. the syntax has changed in modern docker versions to harmonize between the subcommands: `docker volume create <volume-name>`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Data Volume Containers.

## First, create a data volume container

```
docker run -d --name <data-volume-name> -v /<data-volume-name> ubuntu
```

You can add any data you want in this container.

## Create your containers that will share  by using the option volume-from

Let's create container foo and container bar using the shared datacontainer :

```
docker run -it --name foo --volumes-from=<data-volume-name> ubuntu
docker run -it --name bar --volumes-from=<data-volume-name> centos
```

## Enjoy yourself

Each container in my example is mapped to the root folder. 
From either bar or foo you can see **/**, in the filesytem.

Comment: Data volume containers are out of fashion.

Comment: What do you propose instead of data volume containers to do the same job (share persistence data between container) ?

Comment: Docker volumes can be used for that: `docker volume create ...` But in this case the OP really wants to mount a host directory to allow sharing between host and containers.

Comment: Your solution work fine, 

docker volume create --name <volume-name>